# Trouble setting up Ruby with Nginx on CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos, nginx, centos6, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Following the instructions here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-deploy-rails-apps-using-passenger-with-nginx-on-centos-6-5

I get to the point of "Use vim /etc/init.d/nginx to create the start/restart/stop script for nginx" but I can't get the server to start after creating this file and giving it permission to execute. I just get the error `env: /etc/init.d/nginx: No such file or directory` but I can clearly see that the file is where it is supposed to be.

When I try to start nginx directly using `/etc/init.d/nginx start` I get the error `-bash: /etc/init.d/nginx: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Be careful what text editors you use on your local Windows computer.

Comment: I'm using RubyMine 6.3.1. Bad idea?

Comment: You used that to create the `/etc/init.d/nginx` file?

Comment: Yep. I changed the line ending for new files to unix style (\n) and recreated the file from scratch. Now it works. Thanks for cluing me in! Add as answer if you want me to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful what text editors you use on your local Windows computer. Some create Windows-style line endings (`\r\n`, CR-LF), which cause problems like this on Unix-like systems such as Linux or Mac OS X.

If you use such an editor, adjust its settings so that it creates files with Unix-style line endings. If the editor has no such setting, you should not be using it at all.